# Python, JSON TypeError

Tags: python, json, dictionary, typeerror

I'm using the Trello API and have a common problem to others on Stack Overflow. I tried using the solutions provided, but I get a weird error and can't figure out why.

```
cardlist_url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/" + board +  "$
r = requests.get(cardlist_url)
r = r.text
j = json.loads(r)
#Check for when due
print j['due']
```

But on printing `j['due']`, I get:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Which is seemingly at odds with common sense. Incidentally, I put in some integers and it had no effect whatsoever! (I did save it!)

Comment: `j` is a `list` not `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
for i in range(len(J)):
   print "J number " + str(i) + " = " + J[i]
```

That should give you a look inside J

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the JSON output to a dictionary first:

```
j = dict(json.loads(r))
```

And you should be able to access the dictionary by its keys.

Answer (score 0):

What [Ashwini Chaudhary said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534051/python-json-typeerror#comment25499749_17534051)...

Valid JSON files can consist of any combination of lists or dicts.

As a example of the way the JSON module works:

```
import json

listText = '["This","Is","A","Valid","Json","File"]'
dictText = '{"So":["Is","This"]}'

print type(json.loads(listText))
print type(json.loads(dictText))
```

It just depends on how the JSON file you are reading is structured. You will probably want to take into account what has fundamentally changed if the overarching structure of the JSON file is a list.